# Why i can't draw a texture created by bmp properly?

Tags: opengl

So i have a `bmp` file that i want to show it a a quad the problem is that every time texture is split in 2 and the texture the first half is shown next to the other but its reversed.
Examples if the `bmp` is an image of 12  it will split in half 1 and 2 and it will be shown as 21 or or the one in top of the other i tried to use other cords in but nothing worked.

i use the `glOrtho2D(0,300,300,0);`.if that helps and my draw function is :

```
`glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0,0);glVertex2i(300,0);
    glTexCoord2i(0,1);glVertex2i(300,300);
    glTexCoord2i(1,1);glVertex2i(0,300);
    glTexCoord2i(0,1);glVertex2i(0,0);
  glEnd();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your texCoord are wrong:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       glTexCoord2i(0,0);glVertex2i(300,0);
       glTexCoord2i(0,1);glVertex2i(300,300);
       glTexCoord2i(1,1);glVertex2i(0,300);
       glTexCoord2i(1,0);glVertex2i(0,0); // It was repeated
     glEnd();
```

Comment: my bmp loading function was wrong you also have a point for cords but i have tried it so many times changing them nothing was happening so i saw the function again and i fixed thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It was my loading function all along the cords had nothing to do in case you have a problem like check you loading function also.